# Independizar Spinners en lista expandible android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, lista

Buen dia, estoy empezando a trabaja con listas expandibles pero me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

1.Tengo la siguiente lista expandible
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al clickear sobre uno de las preguntas se despliega esta pregunta con un spinner para seleccionar la respuesta correcta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que al instanciar todas las preguntas desde el mismo objeto .xml
al seleccionar una opcion del spinner se selecciona la misma opcion en los demas spinner de cada pregunta, me gustaria saber como puedo independizar estos elementos.

xml pregunta

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPreguntaEst"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtRespuesta1Est"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtRespuesta2Est"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtRespuesta1Est"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtRespuesta4Est"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtRespuesta3Est"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtRespuesta3Est"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtRespuesta2Est"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@color/blueShine"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView16"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtRespuesta4Est" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnComun"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:entries="@array/opcionesRespuestas"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView16"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Slecciona la respuesta correcta"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtRespuesta4Est"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
```

Este es el evento al desplegar la lista

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final String cadenaPregunta = (String)getChild(i,i1);
    if(view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_presentacion_pruebas,null);
    }
    String [] pregunta = cadenaPregunta.split(",");




   txtPregunta = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPreguntaEst);
    txtPregunta.setText(pregunta[1]);

    txtRespuesta1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRespuesta1Est);
    txtRespuesta1.setText(pregunta[2]);

    txtRespuesta2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRespuesta2Est);
    txtRespuesta2.setText(pregunta[3]);


    txtRespuesta3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRespuesta3Est);
    txtRespuesta3.setText(pregunta[4]);


    txtRespuesta4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRespuesta4Est);
    txtRespuesta4.setText(pregunta[5]);



    return view;
}
```

Espero haber sido claro, muchas gracias

Comment: Según tu código, solo tienes un Spinner, lo que puedes hacer teniendo solo un Spinner, sería, crear un objeto que sea List o Array, así el valor que va tomando se va almacenando en el objeto y para usarlo ya solo lo haces por indices.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda gonzalo si me funciono